# command line less.watch()

Tags: css, less

What's the write command line for watching and compiling .less files. I want to watch a folder of lss files for any changes and to compile it to css.

I tried using terminal to cd right into the folder where my .less files are and to just run this command less.watch() but when I made changes nothing got outputted to css file.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog): install watchdog with

```
pip install watchdog
```

or

```
easy_install watchdog
```

Then the [following script](https://gist.github.com/jkeyes/1242040) should do the trick:

```
watchmedo shell-command --patterns="*.less" --command=\
'LESS=`echo "${watch_src_path}" | sed s/.less$/.css/`; \
echo compile: "${watch_src_path}";\
lessc "${watch_src_path}" "${LESS}"; \
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then echo wrote: "${LESS}"; fi' $*
```

It's probably easiest to create an alias for that in your `.bash_profile` (or whatever the equivalent on your system is.

Comment: Your script is not quite correct. If it looks at, say, `dir/thing/static/less/file.less`, it'll compile to `dir/thing/static.css/file.css`. You need a `$` after `s/.less`.

Comment: Thanks! Very good suggestion, I edited the answer acoordingly!